# Magento 1.x - Ajax auto choose product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ajax, jquery

I want after I have pasted sku or name product into the input seach, it will automatically check and notify. I am currently using autoComplete jQuery. But the problem is that if it doesn't show drop down, pressing enter will not work.

> Example: scan barcodes -> auto-complete sku -> automatically select
>   products